# How do I make a rectangle using arrays so that I can have multiple showing on the screen at once?

Tags: python, arrays, pygame, rectangles

The title is pretty self explanatory. I'm trying to find out how to make a rectangle with arrays for this tetris game in python.

Here's the code:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,800))

#Rectangle Variables
x = 200
y = 0
width = 50
height = 50
thickness = 5
speed = 1
#Colors
red = (255,0,0)
white = (255,255, 255)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
while(True):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit (); sys.exit ();
    #These lines ^ make the user able to exit out of the game window
    y = y+1
    pygame.draw.rect((screen) , red, (x,y,width,height), thickness)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Please isolate the issue you are having instead of dumping a code block and saying How to do this?

Comment: No problem I just changed it.

Comment: You must state what the isolated issue is.  We don't write new code for you, you isolate a problem/error and we fix that.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to do it. As of now my code works but I don't know how to include an array in order to create multiple rectangles.

Comment: use `for` loop to get element from array/list and use it with `draw.rect()`

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is add rectangles to an array you could just do:

```
rectangles = []
while(True):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit (); sys.exit ();
    #These lines ^ make the user able to exit out of the game window
    y = y+1
    rectangles.append(pygame.draw.rect((screen) , red, (x,y,width,height), thickness))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Yea I have dimensions and variables listed elsewhere in my existing code. I wanted to know how to set up the rectangle with arrays so that I could create multiple at a time,

Comment: you need to add more of your code to show us then. If you make a loop where you iterate over set X Y cords you could procuderaly make them.

Comment: I added my variables

Comment: @SeanMalhotra I updated my answer so that it might help, could you explain a bit more what you need because it's kind of ambiguous?

Answer (score 0):

If you have list with positions then use `for` loop to draw it.

Here position is in pixels

```
# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

WIDTH = 50
HEIGHT = 50 
RED = (255,0,0)

# --- main ---

rectangles_XY = [ (0, 0), (50, 0), (100, 0) ]

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            # PLEASE, don't put all in one line 
            # it makes code less readable.
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit ()

    for x, y in rectangles_XY:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT), 0)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Here position is in cell positon (column, row)

```
# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

WIDTH = 50
HEIGHT = 50 
RED = (255,0,0)

# --- main ---

rectangles = [ (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0) ]

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            # PLEASE, don't put all in one line 
            # it makes code less readable.
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit ()

    for column, row in rectangles:
        x = column * WIDTH
        y = row * HEIGHT
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT), 0)

    pygame.display.update()
```